# Adding an external executable in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, firefox

I would like to debug Firefox code on OS X.
I'm reading from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Debugging_on_Mac_OS_X) and it tells me:

> Now you need to add the executable. Select Project > New Custom
>   Executable and type a pretty name, then click the Choose button to
>   locate the .app file that you want to debug (Mozilla.app, Firefox.app,
>   DeerParkDebug.app etc). The .app file is

But with xcode 4 there is no Projects menu.  I can't seem to find out how to add a custom executable.  I have successfully built Firefox but I just can't debug it because I don't know how to add an executable in Xcode 4.  I suspect the steps in the link were for Xcode 3.

Answer (score 11):

Under Xcode 4 you will have to edit a scheme to run an executable. Select a scheme (or duplicate one for your target) then select the "Run" phase. You will see an "Executable" pop-up menu, select which executable you wish to use then run your target. There are other settings for specifying the arguments, etc just as in Xcode 3.

Comment: note that if you're using an externally built executable you'll have to remove the target in Build phase for your current scheme in order for the Product > Run action to be able to start the executable