# Stopping at breakpoints in external build in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, debugging

I am trying to debug a large c++ project with Xcode 4. I have to run the executable with a makefile, so I added the project as an external build system. The program does compile and run normally, with the expected outputs. If I edit one file to produce an error during compiling, Xcode notices this and goes to the correct line in the correct file. The problem is that the system doesn't stop at the breakpoints that I set.

I have added the executable in the scheme as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129556/adding-an-external-executable-in-xcode-4). I have added all source files to the project. I have set the custom working directory to the correct one, as was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568810/xcode-4-external-build-project-and-debugging). I have made sure that the executable that I thought is build by Xcode is indeed the one, and I have also tried running it manually after setting the scheme to wait for manual launch, no change.

When I set breakpoints, they show up as blue as they should.

Could somebody give me any hints as to what else I could try? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add -g option to g++ to include debugging information. Helps to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well. I included this line in the makefile and it did the trick

```
#also include debug symbols
CFLAGS+=-ggdb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your project with ccache, lldb won't be able to set breakpoints by file:line

http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20297

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the "Copy files if necessary" check box when importing the source files? It seems that is NOT good. That is what made breakpoint fail for me. I had to remove all source files and re-import them, making sure Xcode did not make separate copies of them. That made the breakpoints work.

I guess XCode could not relate the debug info (-g / -ggdb) with its own copies of the source, or something in that vein.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem (Xcode 8.3.3) but adding -ggdb to the makefile did not fix it. I discovered (after much pain) that the makefile was cleaning up the .o files as part of the build (rm -f $(OBJFILES)). It turns out the symbol information resides in the .o files so by deleting them Xcode could no longer debug. I commented out the rm line and everything now works. I used the -g flag and it works. Anyone battling this should make sure the .o files are around in the proper location.

Answer (score 0):

Adding -g to CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS in makefile will help. You may have to do that for all Makefiles in the project; even the makefile in the inner directories where you are trying breakpoints. That totally depends on your project structure. I had to add in all the 3 Makefile in the project.

It did not work right away for me. I had to delete the .o files manually and build again with the flags added to Makefile.

Also, make sure you have done everything as suggested in the question here.